# Use Spring dependency injection on a custom Hibernate validator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, hibernate-validator

I want to create my own Hibernate custom Validator and what I would like  to do is to add custom logic based on some information gathered from a different context (a different Spring bean)

On my custom implementation, I have tried to both add a constructor and define the validator in a spring bean, or to use the Autowire annotation and none of them worked

Autowire example:

```
public class MyCustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomConstraint, String> {
    @Autowired
    private MyCustomChecker customChecker;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (null == value) {
            return true;
        }

        //get user authenticated properties to perform validation based on the user
        AuthenticatedIdentity identity = Context.getAuthenticatedIdentity();
        return customChecker.isWhitelisted(identity);
    }
}
```

Constructor example:

```
public class MyCustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomConstraint, String> {

    private MyCustomChecker customChecker;

    public MetricDataSizeValidator(MyCustomChecker customChecker) {
        this.customChecker = customChecker;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(CustomConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (null == value) {
            return true;
        }

        //get user authenticated properties to perform validation based on the user
        AuthenticatedIdentity identity = Context.getAuthenticatedIdentity();
        return customChecker.isWhitelisted(identity);
    }
}
```

I've read around on the [official Hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-integration.html#d0e5117) but that doesn't quite answer my question.

I am pretty sure this is a common issue when you want to validate based on some information based from a different context, however I didn't find around an answer for this.

My app is using Spring DI, where my bean is already initialized like this

```
<bean id="customChecker" class="com.mycomp.CustomChecker">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>arg</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Is there any example around of how to achieve this?

**Update**

If I configure my Validator to be:

```
<bean id="validatorFactory" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
<bean id="validator" factory-bean="validatorFactory"
      factory-method="getValidator" />
```

Now I can see the validation is wired up correctly using spring beans. However, now I'm doubtful whether I'm using HibernateValidator (I think I'm not). Is there any way to achieve the same but configure HibernateValidator factory to use Spring beans?

Comment: Have you checked https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator ?

Comment: @Vincz777 maybe I'm missing the point but I don't see any dependency injection used on the custom validator, am I wrong?

Comment: Add `@Component` annotation above the `MyCustomValidator` class. Spring should inject `MyCustomChecker`

Comment: @AndreaGiuliano did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your MyCustomValidator is not recognized as a managed spring bean, so no autowiring will occur.

The easiest way to make your MyCustomValidator a spring bean is to add the @Component annotation at the class level.

Comment: thanks for your comment. However I tried to add @Component and use injection with Qualifier and still is not working. Should I also change the @Constraint(validatedBy = MyCustomValidator.class) somehow in CustomConstraint interface definition?

Comment: Do you ensure that spring does a classpath scanning for beans?

Comment: yeah I do, also most of my beans are defined into an xml file. So I've also tried to defined it in there instead of using @Component annotation, but still have the "javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator:" exception

Comment: so, interestingly, is I configure the Validator in XML to be

<bean id="validatorFactory" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
    <bean id="validator" factory-bean="validatorFactory"
          factory-method="getValidator" />

Then everything works like expected, however I have the suspect I'm not actually using HibernateValidator anymore :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use InitBinder in case of Spring MVC where your custom validator will automatically called by the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.
Simply annotate your method in the controller with @InitBinder and inside the method provide your validator and provide the your validator class to WebDataBinder by calling webDataBinder.setValidator()